# Why does this code print None?

Tags: python, recursion, ackermann

The Ackermann's Function had been tried to implement through the following code

```
def A(m, n):
    if m == 0:
        return n + 1
    elif m > 0 and n == 1:
        A(m - 1, 1)
    elif m > 0 and n > 0:
        A(m - 1, A(m, n - 1))

print A(4, 5)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your function doesn't return anything for 2 of the 3 branches of the `if` statements; only if `m == 0` do you explicitly return a value.

You need to return the results of recursive calls too:

```
def A(m, n):
    if m == 0:
        return n + 1
    elif m > 0 and n == 1:
        return A(m - 1, 1)
    elif m > 0 and n > 0:
        return A(m - 1, A(m, n - 1))
```

Without an explicit return, the function ends with the default return value of `None`.

Comment: thanks. I'd assumed that it automatically returned some sort of a value from the first branch.